# How to use a texture to affect particle density

Tags: particles, weight-painting

I'm trying to get some grass going in super straight lines on a plane. I'd like to use a simple image texture (striped lines) to drive the... weight? Texture density? I'm not even sure of the right terminology, but I want the texture to control the particle density.

I know this involves loading in the texture, and possibly a vertex group, but I'm still fairly new so muddling through hasn't worked yet, and my searches have given very old posts that don't seem to work in 2.8+.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Andy (:

[image: texture for lines]

Answer (score 10):

To control the density of the particles with a texture just create a texture slot in the *Particles Settings > Textures* section.

Then go to the *Texture* settings, load the image file, set the *Influence* to *Density* and *Mapping* to *UV* and select the map. (An empty value uses the default map which is *UVMap*.)

[image: particle settings]

Move the UV island in the *UV Editor* to control the width and number of stripes to your liking. If you have more than one UV map, select the correct UV map from the list (top right in the screenshot). In the *Object Data Properties > UV maps* you can create a new map and also choose it.

[image: UV island]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! Tried it and worked perfectly - really appreciate the time and effort to explain this simply, thanks again (:

Answer (score 8):

This is a PERFECT use case for geometry nodes. If you don't know geometry nodes, let me know, than i will explain my solution in easy steps, but i hope you know it so here is the node tree:

[image]

By changing the float values in the attribute math nodes you can change the look of the grass in the field (width/space).

Result:

[image]

video demo: https://youtu.be/v_aJDsspqnA

Comment: Interesting solution with the sin() function. I would have tried with a modulo function or so and taken the sine for crop circles ;-)

Comment: Thank you!!!!